# Object Arribute Error, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? because, this was migrating peacefully 2 days back

Tags: python

can someone please point me to what exactly I am doing wrong as it keeps popping up AttributeError: type object 'HomePage' has no attribute 'landing'.

The relatedlink object as been properly configured so that the homepage Landing and homepage support inherits from it and utilize it's instance and attribute.

```
# Home Page
class HomePageLanding(Orderable, RelatedLink):
    page = ParentalKey('ibro.HomePage', related_name='landing')
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    background = models.ForeignKey(
        'ibro.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    logo = models.ForeignKey(
        'ibro.IbroImage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
    text = models.CharField(
        max_length=255
    )

    panels = RelatedLink.panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('background'),
        ImageChooserPanel('logo'),
        FieldPanel('colour'),
        FieldPanel('text'),
    ]


class HomePageSupports(Orderable, RelatedLink):
    page = ParentalKey('ibro.HomePage', related_name='supports')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'ibro.IbroImage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    panels = RelatedLink.panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('image')
    ]


class HomePage(Page):
    hero_intro_primary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    hero_intro_secondary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    intro_body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    socialmedia_title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    blog_title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    supports_title = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Homepage"

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title', classname="full title"),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('landing_intro_primary'),
                FieldPanel('landing_intro_secondary'),
            ],
            heading="Landing intro"
        ),
        InlinePanel('landing', label="Landing"),
        FieldPanel('intro_body'),
        FieldPanel('Socialmedia_title'),
        FieldPanel('blog_title'),
        FieldPanel('supports_title'),
        InlinePanel('supports', label="Supports"),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error that's happening?

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'HomePage' has no attribute 'landing'

Comment: That's the error, user2896976, have any idea why that is behaving that way?

Comment: additional info for the error I was getting, which seem t be coming from edit_handers                                                                                                            File "/home/ibrokola/Desktop/NewIbro/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py", line 686, in bind_to_model
    related = getattr(model, self.relation_name).rel

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add additional information, rather than in the comments where it can be overlooked